# What tag to use when asking what word or expression is appropriate to express an idea?

Tags: discussion, support

I just asked this question: [What is a word or expression to describe anxiety about the passing of time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40849/whats-a-word-expression-to-describe-a-feeling-of-anxiety-about-the-passing-of-ti)

It's my first question on English SE, though I am a long-time StackOverflow user, so I understand how the system works in general.

The problem is, I don't know how to tag my question on English SE.  I found the tag `single-word-requests`, which seems appropriate for the question I asked, but on the other hand, I expect that there may be an expression that is more appropriate than a single word.

Please suggest the most appropriate tags for my question.

Comment: **This question is fine here.** Asking for assistance in regards to a question on the main site is almost always on-topic for the meta site.

Comment: The question is about the tags to use in questions asked on the main site; it's not on topic in the main site to ask which tags to use in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests) tag exists specifically for this sort of reverse-dictionary question where the desired answer consists of more than one word. If you're open to any number of words, including one, then use both [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) and the phrase-request tag.

Answer (score 2):

My present understanding of the tags is that they:

1. help experts to answer them (ex. when they favourite them)
2. help those interested in learning/researching about a topic
3. help delimit similar questions

In general you can browse the [list of tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) and see what fits you.
For example *word-choice, phrase-requests, expressions*.
If you think your question is about a common expression or if you want one, there is a tag for that too: *common-expression*. You also have *phrases*, *idioms* and *word-usage*.

Comment: correct; if you can't imagine anyone ever *intentionally* browsing questions with that tag, that tag probably should not exist...